# Begin try/catch doesn't catch select on non-existing table unless using exec('...')?

Tags: sql-server

The catch part will not be run in the following SQL.

```
BEGIN TRY
    select * from notExisting -- The table was renamed and doesn't exist now.
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    select ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

However, the exception will be caught if put the SQL in `exec('....')`?

```
BEGIN TRY
    exec ('select * from notExisting')
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    select ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH
```

I want the exception to be caught in the first SQL in case someone changes the names.

Comment: Your code is missing a lot of semi-colons (`;`).

Comment: Such exceptions are often better handled client-side. SQL Server error handling is quite unreliable, at best.

Comment: It is documented that compilation errors (including errors thrown during deferred resolution recompiles) won't be caught by an error handler at the same scope. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#errors-unaffected-by-a-trycatch-construct

Comment: @GMB, the semi-colons are optional?

Comment: If `nonexisting` exists is already checked at compile time. So you cannot handle that exception at run time there. You need to take a detour like with `EXEC()` or similar.

Comment: could you add IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'yourtable')

Comment: @SEarle1986, it can work. However, I will need to add the checks for every table used in the script.

Comment: Why are you trying to catch this anyway? People randomly changing names without evaluating the impact surely isn't something you should be changing source code to support?

Comment: You should have this type of error handling in your application. You would catch the exception and say "hey man, somebody changed the name of the table now go catch them an ask what they were thinking!!"